# Get two table values using JOIN query where In Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying following query .

```
select a.name b.id ,b.proname , b.date 
from tablea as a tableb as b 
where b.id IN(1,2,3,5) 
group by b.id ;
```

a.name repeat one value all rows

```
a.name b.id b.proname b.date
user   1   user1    12-05-2017
user   2   user2    15-05-2017
user   3   user3    16-05-2017 
user   5   user5    17-05-2017
```

primary key is id

Comment: Your query is rife with problems.  You are currently doing a cross join between the two tables.  If you tell us which columns should be involved with the join, we can possibly correct this.  Also, you are grouping by `b.id`, but selecting many other columns.  This is also wrong.

Comment: What is the primary key of these table ?

Comment: show your both tables data atleast

Comment: You have not mentioned any relation between a and b. Since you are grouping by b.id, a.name will always the first row from the table a.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   a.id b.id same columns both tables

Comment: query not correct because no relation between table a and b. Give sample data if you need help. Here is not some wizard forum that can know how is ur data and table structure

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen +1 for 'rife', which just isn't used enough anymore

Comment: @Strawberry I saw Gordon use it a few weeks ago, and it stuck with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to describe relation between tablea and tableb, something like this:

```
where b.id IN(1,2,3,5) AND a.id = b.id
```

Here a.id and b.id must be in some relation, for example foreign key.

And you using 'GROUP BY' wrong, I think it's not necessary here at all.